# Ruby on Rails link_to js function works only after manual call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, button

I'm fighting with jquery draggable.
I've created button which call function toggleDraggable(), but the problem is that the buton is not responding for clicking.

I've tried to manually call the function through console and  after this button is working fine.

In the source I can see the file is loaded.

here is the function:

```
function toggleDraggable(element, index) {
  var isDisabled = $(element).draggable('option', 'disabled');
  if(isDisabled)
    $(element).draggable('enable');
  else
    $(element).draggable('disable');
}
```

and here is the button code:

```
<%= link_to "STOP", "javascript:elements_array.forEach(toggleDraggable)",   
    class: "btn btn-outline-light nav-item" %>
```

Comment: can you please post how button is loaded?

Comment: Try this `javascript:toggleDraggable()`

Comment: @SaravananN Thank you for helop, i've moved full js code to the toggleDraggable function and now it works.